# Error in load local video path in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have proplem with load video file from locally path with Arabic name in Flutter like:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/Local/Documents/بناء_مشروع_فلتر.mp4

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use a  Flutter plugin for finding commonly used locations on the filesystem. Supports iOS, Android, Linux and MacOS

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```

Please see the example app of this plugin for a full example.

Once you have the path stored in a variable you can append the file name in that path to access any file in the file system

Comment: I can access file with English name, but I have proplem with file that have Arabic name.      Thank you brother for your answer 

Answer (score 0):

```
///Decode the path to utf-8 string
var url = utf8.decode("/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/Local/Documents/بناء_مشروع_فلتر.mp4");
```